# Android Studio 3.1 sync failed, unresolved dependencies

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle

I installed Android Studio 3.3.1 in Windows 10. I'm trying to create my first project, but I'm always getting this error: `Sync failed unresolved dependencies (4 Errors)`.

I tried using a different version of Gradle. I got errors for old versions (as the old versions are not supported in Android Studio 3.3.1), so I tried 4.10.1 and even version 5 without success. I already installed Android Studio on my Mac without a problem, but in Windows it's stuck.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

```
( Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 28, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0)
```

Here the top-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript { 
   repositories { 
       google() 
       jcenter() 
   }
   dependencies { 
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
   }
} 
allprojects { 
   repositories { 
       google() 
       jcenter()
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of code or errors, and create a [mcve]

Comment: Can you add the build.gradle?

Comment: You probably forget to add `google()` repository in your *root* build.gradle.

Comment: google is there   allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir

Comment: Did you install those library in Android SDK?

Comment: Yes I used SDK manager to install them